# Como recorrer el siguiente arreglo en laravel

Tags: laravel, array

soy nuevo en laravel, obtengo este arreglo desde una vista

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta es como puedo recorrer ese array en el controlador, desde ya muchas gracias por la ayuda

Quisiera recorrerlo y grabar dichos datos a una tabla

Comment: Cómo obtienes ese arreglo? Desde un formulario con <input> tags o con javascript?

Comment: Arreglo con inputs

Answer (score 0):

Lo podrías meter en una collection y crear un nuevo arreglo.

```php
$notas = collect($datos)
  ->filter(fn($i, $k) => str($k)->startsWith('notas['))
  ->values();
$notas1 = collect($datos)
  ->filter(fn($i, $k) => str($k)->startsWith('notas1['))
  ->values();
```

Si quieres asegurarte que los números se mantengan en los arrays (`notas[17]` sea `$notas[17]`), puedes ser más explícito al respecto.

```php
$notas = collect($datos)
  ->filter(fn($i, $k) => str($k)->startsWith('notas['))
  ->mapWithKeys(fn($i, $k) => [(string) str($k)->after('[')->before(']') => $i]);

$notas1 = collect($datos)
  ->filter(fn($i, $k) => str($k)->startsWith('notas1['))
  ->mapWithKeys(fn($i, $k) => [(string) str($k)->after('[')->before(']') => $i]);
```

En ambos casos luego puedes recorrer los arreglos con

```php
foreach ($notas as $nota) {}
foreach ($notas1 as $nota) {}
```

---

Agrupando los datos con `groupBy`

```
$notas_agrupadas = collect($datos)
    ->groupBy(fn ($i, $k) => (string) str($k)->after('[')->before(']'));

foreach ($notas_agrupadas as $i => $notas) {
    foreach ($notas as $nota) {
        $nota[0] // notas[$i]
        $nota[1] // notas1[$i]
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero habra una forma de hacer una sola coleccion, me explico que notas1[0] y notas[0] queden en un solo registro y asi con los demas elementos del arreglo

Comment: Con `groupBy` se puede, pero de verdad sería mejor que consiguieras una manera más ordenada de enviar los datos al backend

Comment: Me arroja el siguiente error Call to undefined function App\Http\Livewire\str()

Comment: Estás usando una versión de laravel vieja entonces. Qué pasa si agregas `use Illuminate\Support\Str;` y reemplazas todos los `str($k)` por `Str::of($k)`?

Comment: utilizo la version 8

Comment: ya lo agregue y me arroja el mismo error Call to undefined function App\Http\Livewire\str()

Comment: Se te olvidó guardar el archivo o reemplazar todas las instancias de `str()` por  `Str::of()`. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#fluent-strings.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su ayuda, ya funciona, agradecido